# InetPton() converts any IP to 1.0.0.0

Tags: c++, ip-address, ping, data-conversion, icmp

I am trying to send a ping to some IP through [ICMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx) but the `InetPton()` function, which is suppose to convert string IPs into a binary form, is always returning the same ip: *"1.0.0.0"*.

My code looks like this:

```
short ip[4] = { 192, 168, 1, 2 };

bool checkIP() {
    HANDLE hIcmpFile;
    unsigned long ipaddr = INADDR_NONE;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    char SendData[32] = "Data Buffer";
    LPVOID ReplyBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD ReplySize = 0;

    std::wostringstream strIP;
    strIP << ip[0] << "." << ip[1] << "." << ip[2] << "." << ip[3];

    in_addr ipAddress;
    ipaddr = InetPton(AF_INET, strIP.str().c_str(), &ipAddress);
    if (ipaddr != 1) 
    {
        SendMessage((HWND)StatusBar, (UINT)SB_SETTEXT, (WPARAM)(INT)1 | 0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)TEXT("Invalid IP format!"));
        return false;
    }

    hIcmpFile = IcmpCreateFile();
    if (hIcmpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        SendMessage((HWND)StatusBar, (UINT)SB_SETTEXT, (WPARAM)(INT)1 | 0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)TEXT("Unable to open ICMP handle!"));
        return false;
    }

    ReplySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(SendData);
    ReplyBuffer = (VOID*)malloc(ReplySize);
    if (ReplyBuffer == NULL) 
    {
        SendMessage((HWND)StatusBar, (UINT)SB_SETTEXT, (WPARAM)(INT)1 | 0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)TEXT("Unable to allocate memory!"));
        return false;
    }

    dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho(hIcmpFile, ipaddr, SendData, sizeof(SendData), NULL, ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 2000);
    if (dwRetVal != 0) 
    {
        PICMP_ECHO_REPLY pEchoReply = (PICMP_ECHO_REPLY)ReplyBuffer;
        struct in_addr ReplyAddr;
        ReplyAddr.S_un.S_addr = pEchoReply->Address;
        IcmpCloseHandle(hIcmpFile);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        IcmpCloseHandle(hIcmpFile);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, I am analyzing the network with [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and I can see that the PING is always sent to *1.0.0.0*. I suppose that the problem lies in the `InetPton()` function, but don't understand where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IcmpSendEcho(hIcmpFile, ipaddr, SendData, sizeof(SendData), NULL, ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 2000);
```

Should be:

```
IcmpSendEcho(hIcmpFile, ipAddress, SendData, sizeof(SendData), NULL, ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 2000);
```

Your `ipaddr` is 1, probably this is the source of `1.0.0.0` address.

Comment: Of course, that was the problem. ipAddress should be of type `IPAddr`, too. Thnks

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems a bit off here;

```
in_addr* ipAddress;
ipaddr = InetPton(AF_INET, strIP.str().c_str(), &ipAddress);
```

`ipAddress` will here be an un-initialized pointer to an `in_addr`, which you pass a pointer to into InetPton. What InetPton *really* wants is a pointer to an actual struct/buffer it can fill;

```
in_addr ipAddress;
ipaddr = InetPton(AF_INET, strIP.str().c_str(), &ipAddress);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I can see that the ipAddress variable is filled correctly, yet it looks like the PING is still sent to 1.0.0.0

Comment: @ali `ipaddr` is the status return value of `InetPton`, not the actual ip address. What you should pass into `IcmpSendEcho` is `ipAddress`, not the somewhat confusingly named `ipaddr`.

Comment: Yes. It works now. But only on the local network. I have a router and I suppose that's why. Even with the firewall off, I still can't PING IPs from the Internet

Comment: Are you trying to ping IPs that you actually successfully pinged with a normal ping tool?